# PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory getting when i am running heroku run rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, activerecord, rubygems

I am running postgres 12.3 and in windows.

getting error :

E:\ruby\basic_auth>heroku run rake db:migrate
»   Warning: heroku update available from 7.39.2 to 7.42.5.
Running rake db:migrate on ⬢ rocky-ravine-69290... up, run.6606 (Free)
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:58:in `initialize' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:58:in` new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:58:in `connect' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:46:in` postgresql_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:887:in `new_connection' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:931:in` checkout_new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:910:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:871:in` acquire_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:593:in `checkout' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:437:in` connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1119:in `retrieve_connection' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:221:in` retrieve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:189:in `connection' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:238:in` migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:86:in `block (3 levels) in <main>' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in` each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in `block (2 levels) in <main>' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in` <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in` kernel_load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:463:in` exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in` invoke_command'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in` dispatch'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in` start'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in` with_friendly_errors'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>' /app/bin/bundle:104:in` load'
/app/bin/bundle:104:in `'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

**need help, why this error is coming and how remove it?**

Comment: It would be easier to read such a long printout if you formatted it. Anyway, the *PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server* might be a good place to start at.

Comment: If heroku can't connect to the database you have several possible problems. One could be your config/db.yml file. More likely, you didn't provision a postgres database inside your app on heroku.